SWR measurement: what is considered to be my Load?
I make a simple measurement of SWR of my antenna and a VNA (nanoVNA). I know from theory that the the reflected coefficient id calculated as:
\$ \Gamma = \frac{Z_{L}-Z_{O}}{Z_{L}+Z_{O}} \$, where \$Z_{O}\$ is at the point where the antenna starts (the VNA is calibrated based on the length of the cable).
I am stuck at something very basic: which is my load \$Z_{L}\$ in this measurement? the antenna, or "the air"?
The way I understand it, is that the impedance mismatch and reflections on the desired resonance frequency, are due to the antenna's design VS the surrounding environment (the air). So air (or the surrounding environment of the antenna) should be \$Z_{L}\$. After all, the air is where I want my power to be transmitted to. So to achieve a 0% reflection, the antenna's impedance must match the air's impedance at the resonance frequency. Does that make sense?



which is my load ZL in this measurement? the antenna, or "the air"?

Yes! The impedance is your antenna, including the medium its embedded in (that makes it what it is). Luckily, air is very close to vacuum, so the answer to the question you're asking here is "shrug where's the difference", but this would be different if your antenna was submersed in oil – or in a lens made out of dielectric material, or if your RF frequency was a couple orders of magnitude higher.

The way I understand it, is that the impedance mismatch and reflections on the desired resonance frequency, are due to the antenna's design VS the surrounding environment (the air). So air (or the surrounding environment of the antenna) should be ZL.

The material of air surrounding your antenna (directly on the antenna) contributes to ZL; it's not ZL.
(think about that: if the air was what defined the impedance of an antenna, then all antennas in air would have the same impedance!)
The impedance of "free space" (i.e., air with nothing else in it) is ca 380 Ω (that can be analytically determined from known universal constants, and as said, air being damn near to being vacuum in this range of frequencies).
The job of antenna is actually to be an impedance matching circuit – from the transmission line impedance to free space impedance.
So, no. ZL is not the air. It's what your antenna looks like, surrounded by air, to the network analyzer.

So to achieve a 0% reflection, the antenna's impedance must match the air's impedance at the resonance frequency. Does that make sense?

On the side of free space, yes. On the side of the transmission line, it must match the transmission line. So, an antenna is exactly the kind of shape that, at the frequency it's designed to work at, does its best to convert the transmission line impedance (which is inherently be different than the free space impedance) to the free space impedance.
